# Turned Based Multiplayer Google Play Services Google+ Req

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am looking to hopefully use the Turned Based Multiplayer feature for my android app.  Do I need to have the user login with their google+ account?  If they have a gmail account, do they need to hit a sign in button anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if they have a gmail account, they just click sign in and they're good to go.